# fragments.add() not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a `ViewPager` inside a `Dialog`. I'm using `Fragments`. But my problem is, when I'm trying to call `fragments.add()`I get the Logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.myapp.main cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

I know that the problem is that I'm importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. But if I import `android.app.Fragment` to solve the problem then I can't use my `PagerAdapter`which needs a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Any advice?

My **Dialog:**

```
public void firstlaunch() {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.firstlaunch);
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    d.setCancelable(false);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch3.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch4.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch5.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Firstlaunch6.class.getName()));

    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    d.show();
}
```

My **PagerAdapter:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import java.util.List;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add complete logcat trace rather than a single line. Other part of logcat will show in which line error is.

Comment: Firstlaunch1 class should be a subclass of android.support.v4.app.Fragment can you check the classes that are  adding to the fragments list.